# Why do I have several states change for a BroadcastReceiver On Wifi changes

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-wifi

I want to detect wifi on/off changes. My code below works fine but I go through several iterations of the broadcastreceiver.
For example, if I turn on wifi in the settings, I obtain 8 times false and 2 times true as the value of the boolean coonected.
Is it normal?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView wifistate = null;

BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;
WifiManager wifi;
Context context;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    context = getApplicationContext();

    wifistate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wifistate);
    wifi = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();

            if (action.equals(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)) {
                NetworkInfo info = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
                boolean connected = info.isConnected();
                if (connected) {
                    Log.i("RCVR", "True");
                    wifistate.setText("Connected");
                } else {
                    Log.i("RCVR", "False");
                    wifistate.setText("Disconnected");
                }

            }
        }
    };

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);


}

}
```

and here are the iterations. The end result is correct.

[image]

Comment: Are there other fields in `NetworkInfo` that are changing?

Comment: I just do a switch on/off in settings->wifi

Comment: You didn't answer my question.

Comment: :) I'm not sure I undestand the Q. I'm switching back and force between 4G and wifi. The if (action.equals(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)) means that the event is related to a wifi change? What should I test more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this before. So Here's what I do.

Note: I'm using a different `action` for the receiver.

Here's your solution:

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
```

Then the receiver:

```
BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        if (action.equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = (NetworkInfo) extras.get(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
            boolean connected = info.isConnected();
            if (connected && isWifiConnected()) {
                Log.i("RCVR", "True");
                wifistate.setText("Connected");
            } else {
                Log.i("RCVR", "False");
                wifistate.setText("Disconnected");
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Check if the connected if WiFi or not:

```
public static boolean isWifiConnected() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) appContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    return (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
}
```

This way you are checking if the connection is available and checking if the connection is WiFi.
It seems to work for me. Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't recognize CONNECTIVITY_ACTION. I played with the other  actions but it looks like NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION only works. I'm using min sdk 18.

Comment: `NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` is only a WiFi action. `CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` is for all network types - WiFi, Ethernet, Data, etc.  So what I'm actually doing here is checking when the connection is made and then checking if the connection is made via WiFi

Comment: I applied your code. it gets to the receiver several times (like my code) but doesn't pass if(action.equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION))

Comment: Are you sure you changed the `intentFilter.addAction` line before registering the receiver?

Comment: :) good catch. thanks. I'm down to 2 iterations. when it's on switching to off I get a false false and when it's off switching to on I get a false true. Much better! Many thanks for your time!